# Printing dictionary values in Python

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
a={'*Initial*': {'H': 0.8, 'C': 0.2}, 'C': {'H': 0.4, 'C': 0.6}, 'H': {'H': 0.7, 'C': 0.3}}
```

When I try to print the following:

```
print {k:v[0] for (k,v) in a.items()}
```

I get an error:

```
File "...", line 3, in <module>
    print {k:v[0] for (k,v) in a.items()}
  File "...", line 3, in <dictcomp>
    print {k:v[0] for (k,v) in a.items()}
KeyError: 0
```

Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dictionary, "v" is the value of "k", but "v" is also another dictionary, so you are unable to index it by doing v[0], instead you need to give it a valid key like

```
print {k:v['H'] for (k,v) in a.items()}
```

which would print out the values 0.8, 0.4 and 0.7.