# Printing Total Values in Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a begginer pythonista and currently following a guide [here](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter5/). I am looking at a piece of code in Chapter 5 in a section called Nested Dictionaries and Lists. I have cut some things from the code and it is displayed below:

```
allGuests = {'Carol': {'cups': 3, 'apple pies': 1}, 'Tom': {'cups': 4, 'juice': 4}}

def totalBrought(guests, item):
    numBrought = 0
    for k, v in guests.items():
        numBrought = numBrought + v.get(item, 0)
        return numBrought

print('Number of things being brought:')
print(' - Cups being brought ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'cups')))
```

Below is the output of the above code:

```
Number of things being brought:
 - Cups being brought 3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What the above code should accomplish is to print out the total number of cups that Carol and Tom are bringing. Instead, it prints out only the cups that Carol is bringing. The expected output should be like below:

```
Number of things being brought:
 - Cups being brought 7

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have a looked at an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710200/printing-dictionary-values-in-python) and tried it myself but it isn't what I need. I'm trying to understand the issue with the code and how to properly output the total values, that are the same, within a nested dictionary.

Comment: `return numBrought` - the indentation of this line is wrong. Now it will return at the end of first iteration of the loop, so it will return `3` and not `7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the indentation of return statement:

```
allGuests = {'Carol': {'cups': 3, 'apple pies': 1}, 'Tom': {'cups': 4, 'juice': 4}}

def totalBrought(guests, item):
    numBrought = 0
    for k, v in guests.items():
        numBrought = numBrought + v.get(item, 0)
    return numBrought

print('Number of things being brought:')
print(' - Cups being brought ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'cups')))
```

> Output:

```
Number of things being brought:
 - Cups being brought 7
```

Comment: oh wow. I was relying entirely on the software to yell at me and tell me that something was wrong with the indentation. It seems that both are technically correct so it didn't flag. Thanks! I'll note this for the future.